# How to install genymotion plugin in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, genymotion

I installed **Android Studio 4.1** and **Genymotion 3.1.2** with **VirtualBox 6.0.4**.
I searched Genymotion Plugin in Android Studio but it wasn't there. I tried adding by *downloading jar file and then Install Plugin from disk but that didn't worked either.*
In [Genymotion Website](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) it says click on Browse Repositories and then install plugin but I can't find Browse Repositories option either.

[image]

My question is how can I install Genymotion ? and Why isn't genymotion plugin there in my android studio ?

I have seen similar questions in stack overflow but none of them worked for me and 
Google search gives results about what to do if *genymotion device or icon* doesn't appear **after** *installing genymotion plugin*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems plugin is not required anymore.
I tried to find genymotion in Android Studio the same way. But finally found that Genymotion AVD is already in the list of available devices.
I didn't do any specific installation of the plugin.

You need to create Device in Genymotion first to make it visible in Android Studio.

Android Studio 4.1, Genymotion 3.1.2, VirtualBox 6.1.14

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to install the plugin manually with https://dl.genymotion.com/plugins/idea/1.0.7/genymotion-idea-plugin-20151209.jar . The plugin offers some extra options, like creating, starting or shutting down a device without having to use Genymotion user interface.